# Z-score for multiple columns on groupby and concatenate to same dataset with same column name+"_zscore", tag less than -1 z-score values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A",1,98,56,61], ["B",1,99,54,36], ["C",1,97,32,83],["B",1,96,31,90], ["C",1,45,32,12], ["A",1,67,33,55], ["C",1,54,65,73], ["A",1,34,84,98], ["B",1,76,12,99]], columns=["id","date","c1","c2","c3"])
```

Need to calculate Z-score for columns "c1", "c2", "c3" using groupby on "id", and concatenate to the same dataframe with the same column names +"_zscore". And transform it to the original form. if the z-score value is less than -1, tag as -1 rest as 1, and label the column with the same name+"_tag" without using the loop.

**Expected output:**

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([["A",1,98,56,61,1.21179,-0.079921,-0.543442,1,1,1], ["B",1,99,54,36,0.84893,1.26172,-1.401826,1,1,-1], ["C",1,97,32,83,1.395551,-0.707107,0.860437,1,1,1],["B",1,96,31,90,0.55507,-0.077644,0.539164,1,1,1], ["C",1,45,32,12,-0.89609,-0.707107,-1.402194,1,1,-1], ["A",1,67,33,55,0.025511,-1.182827,-0.858988,1,-1,1], ["C",1,54,65,73,-0.49946,1.414214,0.541757,1,1,1], ["A",1,34,84,98,-1.237301,1.262748,1.40243,-1,1,1], ["B",1,76,12,99,-1.404,-1.184075,0.862662,-1,-1,1]], columns=["id","date","c1","c2","c3","c1_zscore","c2_zscore","c3_zscore","c1_tag","c2_tag","c3_tag"])
```

How to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby().transform` with `scipy.stats.zscore`:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore

df.join(df.groupby('id')[['c1','c2','c3']]
          .transform(zscore).add_suffix('_zscore')
       )
```

Output:

```
  id  date  c1  c2  c3  c1_zscore  c2_zscore  c3_zscore
0  A     1  98  56  61   1.211790  -0.079921  -0.543442
1  B     1  99  54  36   0.848930   1.261720  -1.401826
2  C     1  97  32  83   1.395551  -0.707107   0.860437
3  B     1  96  31  90   0.555070  -0.077644   0.539164
4  C     1  45  32  12  -0.896090  -0.707107  -1.402194
5  A     1  67  33  55   0.025511  -1.182827  -0.858988
6  C     1  54  65  73  -0.499460   1.414214   0.541757
7  A     1  34  84  98  -1.237301   1.262748   1.402430
8  B     1  76  12  99  -1.404000  -1.184075   0.862662
```